# Get the list of files in a directory with in a directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I have a directory named "BaseFile" with in this directory, I have few directories named "Dir1", "Dir2", "Dir3" etc.,

In these sub-directories, I have list of files which I need to get listed via code. Can Some one give me some tips on how to do this?

I need to do this both in windows and Linux platforms..

Comment: Boosthas a nice API for that. The manual is good.

Comment: Do you need a C or only a C++ answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can write this type of code using opendir() and readdir()

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
    DIR           *dirp;
    struct dirent *directory;

    dirp = opendir("/home/user/");
    if (dirp)
    {
        while ((directory = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
        {
          printf("%s\n", directory->d_name);
        }

        closedir(dirp);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Does that work on windows?

Comment: Its for linux,I'm not sure it is working in windows or not

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work for windows too.

Comment: Directory1 inside that there is another Directory, in that I have list of files. I need those files. This code will give list of directories inside a directoyr right?

Comment: @2vision2: This code gives you both directories and files you need to add code for filtering directories

Comment: <dirent.h>  doesn't exist on VS15.

Answer (score 0):

Boost provides a basic_directory_iterator which provides a C++ standard conforming input iterator which accesses the contents of a directory

Refer

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html